# How do I get the last value above my current row in the same column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list of values in Excel, separated by arbitrary spaces/text. I'm trying to find a function that gets the last numeric entry in the column above the row location I'm currently at, and autofill the cell I'm at with it (or let me perform operations on it). Is this possible?

| Column A |
| --- |
| 95000 |
| 46000 |
| NA/BLANK |
| NA/BLANK |
| 52423 |
| NA/BLANK |
| < Fill 52423 here > |

I've tried LOOKUP but couldn't get it to work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you say, *the row location I'm currently at* you essentially want an [R1C1 reference](https://excelchamps.com/formulas/r1c1/) of: `R1C:R[-1]C`? Based on your example, you'd be calling this from `A7` which would make your reference: `A$1:A6`

This formula should work:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A6,MAX(FILTER(ROW(A$1:A6),ISNUMBER(A$1:A6))),1)
```

[image: see... it works.]

Answer (score 0):

Try `INDEX/MATCH` like-

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(99^9,A1:A6))
```

[image]

Comment: bro... that's the second answer you've posted today that is over 2 hours after mine which adds *zero* improvement. In fact I'd argue your answer contains a bug...  copy paste your answer (`=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(99^9,A1:A6))`) from cell `A7` to `A50`....  to see yours `#N/A` while mine holds up to meet the OP's request.

Comment: Do not copy paste formula. Write the formula to `A50`.